# What is the teardrop-shaped appendage on the T-6 Texan?

Tags: aircraft-systems

[image]

Can anyone explain what is the teardrop-shaped item behind the cockpit?

[image]

Comment: Clearly it's not on all models. [this one has it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_T-6_Texan#/media/File:FAC_T-6_with_phosphor_rockets_in_Korea.jpg) but [this one does not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_T-6_Texan#/media/File:GW_T6-RIAT05.JPG) and [this one has something different but in a similar position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_T-6_Texan#/media/File:North_American_T-6G_Texan_5.JPG)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the RDF antenna 'bullet' (or teardrop, actually) fairing. This image shows the (loop) antenna itself.

[image: RDF antenna]

Source: mission4today.com

Initailly, RDF antennas were circular loops mounted above or below the fuselage.

[image: Initial]

"[Earhart-electra 10](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Earhart-electra_10.jpg#/media/File:Earhart-electra_10.jpg)" by Originally uploaded by w:User:Logawi - Transferred from en.wikipedia, description page is/was here.. Licensed under Public Domain via [Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/).

Later loop antenna designs were enclosed in an aerodynamic, teardrop-shaped fairing.

[image: B 17 loop antenna]

Source: airpages.ru

Comment: The change, IIRC, is that the RDFs evolved into ADFs, which rotated to find the relative angle from the nose at which the beacon signal was strongest, allowing the pilot to get a fix from the beacon without having to change course or manually manipulate the antenna. The motorized rotating antenna, however, was much less aerodynamic and prone to damage at high airspeed, so it needed a housing to contain it.